# How to achieve the exact effect of the dropdown menu of riot games' website

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, dropdown

I have to submit a replica of a website to my teacher to get the certificate of frontend web development and I wanted to create riot games' website, however I couldn't find the same dropdown effect the website has. How do I achieve the same effect?

I have linked the website below:
https://www.riotgames.com/en

Thanks!

Comment: Use your browser dev tools inspect facility to see how that site does it. If you are still stuck put the code you have tried into your question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example describing what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) and [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) CSS properties and animate it.
In the following demo, I have used 2 different keyframes to to achieve the effect.
**dropDownAnimation** : At start would show up as a pentagon and then gradually becomes a rectangle by the end
**fadeIn**: Gradually makes the dropdown visible.

You can add more points in between for more control over the animation. For now I've just added 0%, 50% and 100%. Also, you might need to play with the animation-duration property.

```js
const btnToggleDropdown = document.querySelector("#toggle-dropdown");
const content = document.querySelector("#content");
btnToggleDropdown.addEventListener("click", () => {
  content.classList.toggle("dropdown");
});
```

```css
.content {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.dropdown {
  animation: dropDownAnimation 200ms forwards, 
              fadeIn 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes dropDownAnimation {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 10%, 25% 10%, 0 10%);
  }

  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 40%, 25% 70%, 0 40%);
  }

  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
  <button id="toggle-dropdown">Toggle Efffect</button>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
```